# Connect an external SQL databse to .NET microservice pods in Kubernetes

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have created .NET microservices pods in Kubernetes,and want to connect these pods to the external SQL database present on-premises. I have made all the possible changes to the connection string, added `TrustServerCertficate=True` and `Encrypt=False`, but still no luck.

I have added Hostalises, property in deployment file, with IP address and and the corresponding hostname.

[Pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxOJ1.png)

Currently I am working on master-api pod,below the connection string details,

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "con": "data source=DB_name; database=admin_table; user id=admin; pwd=admin; Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=500;timeout=40000; TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False"
    },
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[Kubectl get svc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhcxv.png)
svc for this microservice is master-service

This is the deployment file with service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: master-api
  labels:
    app: master-api
    type: back-end
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: master-api
      labels:
        app: master-api
        type: back-end
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: masterapi
          image: repo/mpsaps-masters:v1.14
          env:
          - name: HTTP_PROXY
            value: http://proxy-details
          - name: HTTPS_PROXY
            value: http://proxy-detail
      hostAliases:
          - ip: "hostip"
            hostnames:
            - "hostname"

      
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: back-end

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: master-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: master-api
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      port: 3040
      nodePort: 31902
```

This is the docker-compose file which I am using.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  MasterApi:
   image: repo/mpsaps-masters:v1.14
   container_name: mpsaps-master
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Mpsaps.Masters/Dockerfile
   environment:
    - HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy
    - HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy
  
   ports:
    - "443:443"
    - "1433:1433"
    - "42016:80"
```

When I run the curl command to fetch the data from DB, the following error occurs all the time:

```
curl 'http://192.168.100.1:31902/PublicService/GetServiceByDepartment?Dep_Code=%2201%22'
```

```
{"response":{"response_code":"0","response_message":"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)","result":null}}
```

Please any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if `kubectl logs` shows more information about the exception getting raised via the container's STDOUT.

Comment: Aside... `timeout=40000` means it should wait forty thousand seconds to establish a connection - that's nearly half a day, perhaps too long.

Comment: How about disable the firewall

Comment: firewall is already disabled @QiangFu

Comment: @AlwaysLearning but connection is already connected.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning below are the logs

Comment: The shown `kubectl logs` don't seem at all related to the SQL connection error. The three possibilities that come to mind are 1) you're using a port number with a colon such as `Data Source=DB_name:portNumberHere;` instead of with a comma `Data Source=DB_name,portNumberHere;` or 2) you're connecting to a port that doesn't actually have an SQL Server instance listening on it, or 3) you're connecting to a very old or very new version of SQL Server (what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`?) that's using a TLS protocol version not supported by the version of OpenSSL that's installed in your pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have got the issue resolved, it was happening because the sql server version on which i am creating connection is not supported by kubernetes, so i have updated the version and now its works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

these are the logs

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HMUEBFQB5I9F", Request id "0HMUEBFQB5I9F:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Mpsaps.Masters.Controllers.PublicServiceController.GetkuberTest() in /src/Mpsaps.Masters/Controllers/PublicServiceController.cs:line 63
at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).